# Convert canvas to image and null reference

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have function to convert `Canvas` to `Image`:

```
public async void CreateImage(Canvas canvas)
{
    Image image = new Image();
    int width = Convert.ToInt32(canvas.ActualWidth);
    int height = Convert.ToInt32(canvas.ActualHeight);

    RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(canvas, width, height);
    image.Source = renderTargetBitmap;
    frameList.Add(image);
}
```

and `frameList` is a list of `Image` but on `frameList.Add(image);` I get `NullReference` any idea why? And how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure `frameList` is not null simply?

Comment: @KonradKokosa is correct, you would only get a `NullReference` error if you were trying to do `null.Add(image)`.  Sounds like `frameList` is not instantiated.  Can you post that code?

Comment: @KonradKokosa awww.... my bad, you'r right